# Perform 2 functions OnClick ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hope you are all good.

I have button onclick that call 2 functions BUT it is not working and i dont have any errors displaying in the console, so i don't know where the problem is.

Here is my code

```
  <div className="d-grid gap-2">
            <Bouton btnCss = 'btn btn-success my-3' 
             click= { () => { this.props.handleSubmit; this.setState({begin : true})}}>
              Commencer la tâche
             </Bouton>
            </div>
        </form>
       
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default withFormik({
    mapPropsToValues : () => ({
        tache : '',
        unite : '',
        commentaire : ''

    }),
    validationSchema : Yup.object().shape({
        tache : Yup.number()
        .required('Choisissez une tâche'),
        unite : Yup.number()
        .required('Choisissez une unite'),
        commentaire : Yup.string()
        .min(5, 'Le Texte est trop court')
        .required('Veuillez entre un texte')
    }), 
    handleSubmit : (values, {props, resetForm}) => {
        resetForm();
        props.validation(values.tache, values.unite, values.commentaire);
    }
})
(taskForm)
```

Thank you for your help mates !

Comment: Is any of the functions running at all? Also why not incorporating the second function with handleSubmit

Comment: `onClick` but not `click`.

Comment: @JorgeGuerreiro functions are working great, but i can't do this.setstate in the handleSubmit, i have an error cant access it

Comment: @AndrewF class Bouton <button onc-Click = {props.click}>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling your `this.props.handleSubmit`

It should be `this.props.handleSubmit()`

When you were previously calling your function you were using:

```
<Bouton click= {this.props.handleSubmit}>Commencer la tâche</Bouton>
```

You were in fact passing to your custom component a reference to the function that will be called when the button is clicked.

The button then calls the function. You could say the onClick function adds the `()`

Like you would when you're getting a callback in your arguments:

```
const functionWithACallback = (callback) =>
{
   // Do stuff
   callback();
}
```

However now what you are doing is passing an anonymous function to be called when your button is clicked. You're passing:

```
() => {
    this.props.handleSubmit; 
    this.setState({begin : true})
}
```

However here, this.props.handleSubmit is never called.

Also comments made and the other answer are the good practices to follow namely:

1. You should follow the react naming conventions and name your button click handler `onClick` instead of `click`.
2. You should create a separate function named `handleClick` and call it when your button is clicked to keep your return statement as lean as possible.

Comment: Hoow ?? Yes it did work finally but when i called just this.props.handleSubmit it worked fine, but not the second function and now i add this.props.handleSubmit() and it worked im kinda lost

Comment: I edited my answer with further explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you call one function, that calls the next two functions? Something like this:

```
handleClick() {
   function1();
   function2();
}


<Bouton btnCss = 'btn btn-success my-3' 
             onClick= { () => { this.handleClick() }}>
              Commencer la tâche
             </Bouton>
```

You can always add `async/await` if you need to wait for the 1st one to complete before you fire the 2nd one.

Comment: This won't work, onClick would

Comment: No it won't because Bouton is a custom component.